# Advanced Custom Fields plugin User dropdown is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the ACF plugin in one of the WordPress websites and I have the following configuration for a user dropdown. This is added as a PHP code.

```
acf_add_local_field_group(array (
      'key' => 'group_557ad1ef2b8a1',
      'title' => 'Authors',
      'fields' => array (
        array (
          'key' => 'field_557ad24ba99e5',
          'label' => 'Featured',
          'name' => 'featured_authors',
          'type' => 'repeater',
          'instructions' => 'Choose a maximum of 6 authors',
          'required' => 0,
          'conditional_logic' => 0,
          'wrapper' => array (
            'width' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'id' => '',
          ),
          'min' => '',
          'max' => 6,
          'layout' => 'table',
          'button_label' => 'Add Author',
          'sub_fields' => array (
            array (
              'key' => 'field_5582bc82f8419',
              'label' => 'Author',
              'name' => 'featured_authors_author',
              'type' => 'user',
              'instructions' => '',
              'required' => 1,
              'conditional_logic' => 0,
              'wrapper' => array (
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
              ),
              'role' => '',
              'allow_null' => 0,
              'multiple' => 0,
            ),
          ),
        )
      'menu_order' => 0,
      'position' => 'normal',
      'style' => 'seamless',
      'label_placement' => 'top',
      'instruction_placement' => 'label',
      'hide_on_screen' => array (
        0 => 'the_content',
        1 => 'author',
        2 => 'featured_image',
      ),
    ));
```

Now from the admin section, I am trying to add this field to the page, but it is not permitting the admin to select users. The dropdown is showing without any values. I am using the following versions:

Wordpress - 5.7.3

Advanced Custom Fields - 5.4.5

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code. You didn't close the first array() inside the 'fields' parameter in your main list of fields. Before this line:

```
'menu_order' => 0,
```

you need to add this:

```
),
```

This will close the 'fields' parameter, and allow it to process the parameters that appear after it.

I ended up recreating your field group in the ACF User Interface in the WP Admin, then exported the php, stripped out all the unnecessary/default parameters, and it's working great for me on a test environment. See the code below. I stripped out all of the settings that were just set to the default settings, to help make things a bit more readable.

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_local_field_group') ):

acf_add_local_field_group(array(
    'key' => 'group_6148d6a5d8172',
    'title' => 'Authors',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'field_6148d6afde7ec',
            'label' => 'Featured',
            'name' => 'featured_authors',
            'type' => 'repeater',
            'instructions' => 'Choose a maximum of 6 authors',
            'max' => 6,
            'button_label' => 'Add Author',
            'sub_fields' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'field_6148d6d5de7ed',
                    'label' => 'Author',
                    'name' => 'featured_authors_author',
                    'type' => 'user',
                    'required' => 1,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'location' => array(
        array(
            array(
                'param' => 'post_type',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'post',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'style' => 'seamless',
    'hide_on_screen' => array(
        0 => 'the_content',
        1 => 'author',
        2 => 'featured_image',
    ),
));

endif;
```

One thing I noticed is that your code doesn't have any Location settings to dictate what post type or other element the field group should appear on, so I set my example to appear on every Post. You may need to adjust this to match your needs.

I also included the if function_exists conditional wrapper so that if you turn off the ACF plugin, it won't generate errors when it cannot find the acf_add_local_field_group() function.

Comment: Thanks. I actually copied this from the code which has a lot of other fields and so the closing of the brackets and the location settings not appearing there. For me, the issue is that in the dropdown,  it is not showing any of the users. When I checked the select box code, it is showing as empty.

Comment: Does your original code also include some location rules to dictate what posts/pages this field group should appear on? Because without those settings they won't appear anywhere.

Comment: If I take your code from the question, add a closing parenthesis, and add the location rules from my answer, the repeater field appears for me on a clean WP install with twentytwentyone theme, if I add an author, it's giving me a dropdown where I can select any registered user I create.